# Getting Error: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" only in production setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

vue Version: 2.1.1

I am getting following error, only in production setup:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> at s.updated (vue.common.js:6077)
>
> at we (vue.common.js:2754)
>
> at De (vue.common.js:2831)
>
> at Array. (vue.common.js:473)
>
> at e (vue.common.js:422)

This works perfectly in the local setup, but only in production I get this error. When I go to  `s.updated (vue.common.js:6077)` line from chrome console, I get following code:

```
var TransitionGroup = {
  props: props,

  render: function render (h) {
    var tag = this.tag || this.$vnode.data.tag || 'span';
    var map = Object.create(null);
    var prevChildren = this.prevChildren = this.children;
    var rawChildren = this.$slots.default || [];
    var children = this.children = [];
    var transitionData = extractTransitionData(this);

    for (var i = 0; i < rawChildren.length; i++) {
      var c = rawChildren[i];
      if (c.tag) {
        if (c.key != null && String(c.key).indexOf('__vlist') !== 0) {
          children.push(c);
          map[c.key] = c
          ;(c.data || (c.data = {})).transition = transitionData;
        } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
          var opts = c.componentOptions;
          var name = opts
            ? (opts.Ctor.options.name || opts.tag)
            : c.tag;
          warn(("<transition-group> children must be keyed: <" + name + ">"));
        }
      }
    }

    if (prevChildren) {
      var kept = [];
      var removed = [];
      for (var i$1 = 0; i$1 < prevChildren.length; i$1++) {
        var c$1 = prevChildren[i$1];
        c$1.data.transition = transitionData;
        c$1.data.pos = c$1.elm.getBoundingClientRect();
        if (map[c$1.key]) {
          kept.push(c$1);
        } else {
          removed.push(c$1);
        }
      }
      this.kept = h(tag, null, kept);
      this.removed = removed;
    }

    return h(tag, null, children)
  },

  beforeUpdate: function beforeUpdate () {
    // force removing pass
    this.__patch__(
      this._vnode,
      this.kept,
      false, // hydrating
      true // removeOnly (!important, avoids unnecessary moves)
    );
    this._vnode = this.kept;
  },

  updated: function updated () {
    var children = this.prevChildren;
    var moveClass = this.moveClass || ((this.name || 'v') + '-move');
    if (!children.length || !this.hasMove(children[0].elm, moveClass)) {    // <=== This is the line throwing error
      return
    }
```

I have lot of code in the repo with involvement of multiple components so not sure what code to put here which can help the community debug.

**Code requested**:

I am only using `transition-group` in one of the component, which is being used just before navigating to this page:

```
<transition-group tag="ul" name="prod-covered" class="prod-box">
  <li :key="index" v-for="(prod, index) in prods" v-if="prod" class="prod">{{prod}}</li>
</transition-group>
```

Here prods is static data which is being passed as props to that component.

Comment: Either `this.prevChildren` is `undefined` or `this` is not what it should be

Comment: Add a code that uses the transition group, it seems that elements that you try to animate do not exist, can possibly happen when the component (nodes tree) is detached from the actual document tree.

Comment: @yev but why this might be coming only in production, I have still added relevant code.

Comment: 2.2.6 - error is still there.

Comment: I got objects on page with move animation

Comment: And when I change route path with route.push('home') - I got this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had accidentally ended up with 1 child in a `transition-group`, and this would cause the error. I only used transition-group if there was more than one child in it, and that solved the problem.

The error would only show up once we tried to go to a different page, triggering an `update()`.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to latest version: `2.2.1` and not seeing that error after upgradation, seems they might have fixed in it this version.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `children` exist before accessing the length.

Change

```
if (!children.length || !this.hasMove(children[0].elm, moveClass)) {
```

to

```
if (!children || !children.length || !this.hasMove(children[0].elm, moveClass)) {
```